# arcpy symbologyType is always OTHER, but I need UNIQUE_VALUES

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, unique-value

I am trying to load a TIF file to the mxd using arcpy, then add a definition file to map colouring.

For one layer I have the problem, that the amount of values will always be different, sometimes it will be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 sometimes it will be 0,7,8 and sometimes it will be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,34

So i created in ArcMap an empty layer definition file: BEST_SERV_MO99.lyr
when added the TIF layer to the mxd, I am applying this. Now I would like to add all values except 0...
Also I would like to set the alpha to be 50%.

when I try the following code:

```
outRaster = os.path.join(path_now, tif_file)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outRaster)
self.log("addLayer: "+ addLayer.name)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(self.df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
for layer in layers:
   if layer.name == tif_file:
       layer.name = tif2_file
       if os.path.isfile(symbologyLayer):
           arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer,symbologyLayer)
           self.log("layer: "+layer.name+" - symbologyType: "+layer.symbologyType)
```

I am always getting symbologyType: OTHER
The problem is, with OTHER, I can not add all values like this:

```
if layer.symbologyType == "UNIQUE_VALUES":
   layer.symbology.addAllValues()
```

also I have tried to do according [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76427/managing-symbology-in-feature-classes):

```
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, True)
```

but this did not have any effect, layer.symbologyType was still OTHER.

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3 with Python 2.7

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.

Comment: edited my question, see above: ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3 with Python 2.7

Comment: No one has a solution, how I can dynamically add all values?