# Getting ArcMap layer with symbologyType = "UNIQUE_VALUES"?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology

I am trying to write an automated mapping script to set new categories for a layer on each iteration, however I have encountered a problem.

If I understand it correctly may layer's symbologyType should be "UNIQUE_VALUES" to be able to modify the available categories. However my dataset has the symbologyType "OTHER".

Now I understand that symbologyType is a read-only attribute and I need to use UpdateLayer to create a new layer with the desired type, but where do I get a layer with the symbologyType "UNIQUE_VALUES" to do this?

All layers I have created have type other.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1

Comment: Please update your question to include a code snippet/what you've tried. I want to verify it's actually looking at the layer properties instead of a list for example. Also how were the layers created (arcpy, interatively in Desktop?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76427/managing-symbology-in-feature-classes.  It looks like you can create a lyr file that has the desired symbology type then apply that through updateLayer.

Comment: smiller - The layers is a point layer that was created via geocoding a list of placenames. I am trying to use layer.symbolodyclassValues to add a specific list of values to display, but I can't because it's of a symbologyType "OTHER". Also it is not a duplicate, because to apply the methodology you linked I need to have a layer of a "UNIQUE_VALUES" type, which I do not and have not been able to produce.

Comment: If I'm understanding the other question's reply - create manually in ArcMap a layer in your map with unique values as symbology, and save as layer on disk. Then that can be used in the update layer process.